# "Heaven's Gate" vs "The Gates of Hell"

Tags: articles

How come "Heaven's Gate" has no articles, whereas "The Gates of Hell" does?

Is this because Heaven's Gate is a kind of proper noun, like Notting Hill Gate or Lancaster Gate?

Comment: One can also write "The Gates of Heaven" or "Hell's Gates," so it's not a peculiarity of Heaven.

Comment: Like "Hell's Kitchen", for example.

Comment: I've seen many depictions showing Heaven to have one single gate, while I guess the idea is that Hell has multiple?  Maybe the implication is there's only one way to get into Heaven, but many ways to get into Hell?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, in general, I'm pretty sure I've seen the plural "gates" used to describe a single opening that happens to have a two-part door. Perhaps that's part of the issue?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi e.g. "The Pearly Gates" - another name for "Heaven's Gate", but that one's always plural.  Go figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put "the" in front of either *gates of heaven* or *gates of hell*.

And it can be one gate or more, though in the King James Version of the Bible:

- "gate of heaven" appears once.
- "gate of hell" doesn't appear.
- "gates of hell" appears once.
- "gates of heaven" doesn't appear.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heaven%27s%20gate%2Cthe%20gates%20of%20heaven%2Chell%27s%20gate%2Cthe%20gates%20of%20hell&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheaven%20%27s%20gate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20gates%20of%20heaven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chell%20%27s%20gate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20gates%20of%20hell%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cheaven%20%27s%20gate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20gates%20of%20heaven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chell%20%27s%20gate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20gates%20of%20hell%3B%2Cc0) compares the popularity (in literature) of each of these phrases:
heaven's gate, hell's gate, the gates of heaven, the gates of hell.

Comment: The spike in "Heaven's Gate" around 1997 is probably due to the [suicide cult of that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven%27s_Gate_(religious_group)) that offed themselves at that time.

Comment: Is it "King James' version" or "the King James version"?

Answer (score 12):

Both of the expressions you cited contain determiners:

1. "Heaven's Gate": the determiner is a possessive noun ("Heaven's")

A nominal phrase usually takes only one determiner. "Gate" already has a determiner ("Heaven's"), and the proper noun "Heaven" does not normally take a determiner. Therefore, there is no need to add any.

2. "The Gates of Hell": the determiner is a definite article ("The")

You might omit a determiner before "gates of Hell", for example if you were talking about such gates in general. However, I think that such a situation would be unusual. Because this expression typically refers to specific gates, it is common to include a determiner (such as "the") before it, whether it is considered a proper noun or not.

Comment: When my father was more than usually vexed, he might say 'Hell's bells!'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Exactly the sort of situation described in the last paragraph: “the Gates of Hell” are one specific set of gates. “Hell’s bells” are any and all bells found in Hell. So the former gets the determiner and the latter does not. Also, [obligatory AC⚡DC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etAIpkdhU9Q).

Comment: @KRyan I'd say that "Hell's Bells" was more similar in construction to "Heaven's Gate": The first word of the phrase is a determiner (a possessive noun). "[The] Bell's of Hell" would be like the situation described in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Using *the* in front of a possessive has another meaning. For example, “[the Moon’s orbit](https://moon.nasa.gov/resources/429/the-moons-orbit/) is the orbit of *the Moon*. [*The Pilgrim’s Progress*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/131) is the progress of an allegorical pilgrim, who represents all believers.  “[T]he Federal Competitiveness and Statistics Centre announced the UAE's GDP at constant prices,” means the gross domestic product of *the United Arab Emirates*.  That is, it is possible to take the possessive of some phrase that contains a definite article.  But note that it is much more common to say, for example, “the Netherlands anthem” or “the Dutch anthem” than “the Netherlands’ anthem.”

This gets more ambiguous with more complex examples.  “[T]he layers of Hell's sins” means in context the respective sins of each layer of Dante’s *Inferno*, but “I feel that I am able to see all the way down through the layers of hell's stomach.” could mean either one metaphorical stomach which all layers of Hell share, or that Hell has a layered stomach.  (It’s not, in my opinion, a particularly well-written sentence.)  This might be why that construction is so rarely used.

Additionally, references to theological concepts like Heaven and Hell in English tend to use more conservative grammar, because of the continuing influence of the 17th-century King James translation of the Bible.  In this style of formal, written, early-modern English, the possessive suffix could not be used on inanimate objects such as a gate (although “soul’s” is animate enough to appear once), and the word *its* was still considered too informal.  (Although William Shakespeare, writing at the same time, did already use both the modern way.)  This means you will see a lot more uses of possessive *of* than you normally do.  And in particular, “the gates of Hell shall not prevail against it,” is a more well-known quote than, “this is none other but the house of God, and this is the gate of heaven.”

Answer (score 0):

The main point is that Heaven and Hell themselves come into this only to confuse the issue. "The Gates of Location" and "Location's Gate" or "Location's Gates" are wholly interchangeable, and so is "The Gate of Location".

A secondary point is that just as they are interchangeable, each is indeed a kind of proper noun, like Lancaster Gate, et al.

We normally think of nouns as referring to people, things or places where people always, things never and places sometimes are promoted to "proper nouns" which demand initial capitals.

"Fairfield Farm" is a proper noun; "that farm over there" is not, for the reason that "Fairfield Farm" is identifiable in and of itself; "that farm over there" only by external reference.

"Heaven" is a proper noun; "that place up there" is not; the difference between Heaven and Heaven's Gate is purely one of scale.

A tertiary point is that even singular "gate" and plural "gates" are often interchangeable… imagine an Earthly city - or mere estate - with at least one gate-way, and consider why I used "gate-way" rather than "gate" or "pair/set of gates"?

Even of a pair of gates, many people not actually looking at them will use "the gate…" That is because the term refers to the location, not to the mechanical structure. We would never pluralise a single gate but we very often singularise a pair.

A description of someone leaning on the gate or gates is much more likely to be literal, because describing someone leaning necessarily involves the mechanics.

"He leaned on the gate…" is slightly different from "he leaned on the gates…". "He leaned one arm on each gate…" is too unlikely.

If there's a contradiction with "Heaven's Gate" is that not more with "The Pearly Gates" than "The Gates of Hell"?

Answer (score 0):

Almost separately, another complication is that some gates have no gates in the modern sense… in fact, the opposite. The WWW is full of references suggesting the development of the very word “gate” started with the gap in the wall, not the thing that blocks it.

Today we think of a fixed gateway, closed by a moving gate but the suggestion is that long before there was even German, let alone English, various forms of spellings and pronunciations referred to a passage, road or street, or to a hole or opening through which that passed.

Consider also “gait” which we tend to see as “style of walking” and how greatly that changes if it refers not to a “style” but to a “way of walking.”